# help solving limit with integral inside

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 3} \dfrac{\int_9^{x^2} \frac{\sqrt{t}(\sqrt{t}-3)}{t-5}\ dt}{(x-3)^2}$

not sure how to approach this limit. I have tried simplifying the function by solving the integral but I can't get it into a usable form. The integral is not coming out nicely at all so I'm not sure what to do with it. can I get this in a form for L'Hopital?

Comment: What did you get when you applied L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: I was worried about the integral. How do I get the numerator to evaluate to infinity or 0?

Comment: You can put $t=u^2$ in the integral and then apply L'Hospital's Rule. You should then get the answer almost instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply L'Hopital's rule by [differentiating the definite integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll work on the integral. I was not able to evaluate it earlier but I think I may have messed up when solving the integral so I'm on the right track with L'Hopital at least.

Comment: You don't have to "solve" the integral in order to differentiate it!

Comment: aaah, this makes sense. just got up for the morning, going to sub-in right now. Thank you for the help!